# Implemetning Tree with Map

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, hashtable, binary-tree

I have a binary tree like -

```
            1
           / \
          3   5  
             / \  
            7   9
```

Now I'm trying to represent the tree using `HashTable`. So I have created a `HashTable` `binaryTree` -

```
HashTable binaryTree = new HashTable<Integer, Intgeger>();
```

Then I am trying to add item to the `binaryTree`. I want `1` to be as a key of the binaryTree and all of it's child (for example - 3 and 5) as it's value. So I am trying to put -

```
binaryTree.put(1, 3);
binaryTree.put(1, 5);
```

Since there are 2 values with key 1, so the second one is not inserted into the HashTable - binaryTree?

How can I add both 3 and 5 to the `binaryTree`? 
Or is there any better data structure to do this?

Thanks in advance?

Comment: You'd need two maps -- one for left child and one for right child -- if you're going to do it like this, or you could have a map from `Integer` to a type representing a pair of integers.  Or you could not do it with a Map at all, but represent the tree as an object type itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to "fold" adjacency lists into a single hash table. That's possible, but you need to change the type of the element to something capable of holding two integers.

The most common approach would be using a `TreeNode` class:

```
class TreeNode {
    private final int left;
    private final int right;
    public int getLeft() { return left; }
    public int getRight() { return left; }
    TreeNode(int l, int r) { left = l; right = r; }
}

HashTable<Integer,TreeNode> binaryTree = new HashTable<Integer,TreeNode>();
```

Now the insertion would look like this:

```
binaryTree.put(1, new TreeNode(3, 5));
```

You could also use an array of two `int`s instead of a custom class, but the code using such representation would not be as readable:

```
HashTable<Integer,int[]> binaryTree = new HashTable<Integer,int[]>();
binaryTree.put(1, new int[] { 3, 5 });
```

Comment: Wow! So in the second case I can use array/arrayList to represent more thant 2 children. So I think the second one can be used to represent any tree, am I right?

Comment: @Razib Yes, the second approach can be used to represent a tree with any number of children per node.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to implement the second one.